# Get image URL from MWPhoto?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ios4

I am using the MWPhotoBrowser [(here)](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) and I am trying to get the image that you are currently on.

I try this:

```
MWPhoto *theObject = [photos objectAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
NSString *test = [theObject image];
NSLog(@"maybe? %@", test);
```

And I get this

```
maybe? <UIImage: 0x4e5e890>
```

That's good an all, but I want to get the URL of the current image.

Any help is appreciated, 
 Coulton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in MWPhoto.h add:

```
- (NSURL *)url;
- (NSString *)path;
```

at line 45

in MWPhoto.m add:

```
// Return URL
- (NSURL *)url { return self.photoURL; }

// Return Path
- (NSString *)path { return self.photoPath; }
```

at line 88

Where your code is, do something like

```
MWPhoto *theObject = [photos objectAtIndex:currentPageIndex];
NSString *path = [theObject path];
NSURL *url = [theObject url];
NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
NSLog(@"path %@", path);
NSLog(@"url %@", path);
```

To make use of the NSURL, check out http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: -[MWPhoto photoURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e5a8e0 -- I don't think it's declared in the MWPhotoBrowser.m file is (which is where my code is).

Comment: If you take a look in MWPhoto.h, you can see the members of MWPhoto which are: photoPath, photoUrl, photoImage, and workingInBackground.  'image' returns you 'photoImage', but there aren't functions for photoPath and PhotoUrl like you want.  You can look in MWPhoto.m, at the 'image' function and write accessors for the properties you want returned.

Comment: @John: Can you please write up an example? Something I can read from another class file? Like `MWPhotoBrowser *MWBrowser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] init];
 NSURL *test = [MWBrowser.theObject photoURL];
 NSLog(@"maybe? %@", test);` Thanks!

Comment: Edited the answer to give you some more information and where to do things, just be warned, there's no checking of those values, you'll want to put in any error checking etc, or just be real careful like :)

Comment: When putting in my .h like this `
#pragma mark NSObject


// Return URL
- (NSURL *)url { return self.photoURL; }

// Return Path
- (NSString *)path { return self.photoPath; }` I get `Accessing Unknown photoURL getter method` and `Accessin unknown photoPath getter method`... Please help!

Comment: What file did you put that in?

Comment: If you added it to both files it should know what's going on, unless maybe you have a different version and things are different, which is possible.  In a nut shell, you want to look into MWPhoto.h, and MWPhoto.m.  Fine the property in MWPhoto.h that you need to access and see if there's a function that already gives you access to it, probably not.  But notice how they give you access to the 'photoImage' property, though the 'image' function that you already used.  If you duplicate how that works, you should be able to access what you're trying to get.

Comment: um, you just went over my head. it's letting me put it as `photoURL` instead of `self.photoURL` and it works fine but in my consle, it returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

In case, if there are some other people looking for solution, I hope this one will help.

I have used MWPhotoBrowser for quite a long time already. Previously, in their .h file, we can take photoUrl. Now they move to .m and we can't access that property outside.

Since I am using that library from cocoapods, I also don't want to modify their code. So, I create category like this. I will assign photoUrl separately in MWPhoto.

In MWPhoto+Property.h,

```
#import <MWPhotoBrowser/MWPhotoBrowser.h>

@interface MWPhoto (Property)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *photoUrl;
@end
```

In MWPhoto+Property.m,

```
#import "MWPhoto+Property.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation MWPhoto (Property)

static char UIB_PROPERTY_PHOTOURL;

@dynamic photoUrl;

- (void)setPhotoUrl:(NSURL *)photoUrl {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_PHOTOURL, photoUrl, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSURL *)photoUrl {
    return (NSURL *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIB_PROPERTY_PHOTOURL);
}


@end
```

Then, when I initialise MWPhoto, I put for photoUrl too.

```
NSURL *photoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:messageData.dataDict[@"image"]];
MWPhoto* photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:photoUrl];
photo.photoUrl = photoUrl; //Due to new implementation in MWPhotoBrowser, property of photoUrl is hidden. So, i put in category
[self.photos addObject: photo];

//Later, you can access photo.photoUrl in other places.
```